# Deleting a row with Php & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am new to php and SQL and just toying around with a project for my own understanding of accessing, updating and deleting data from my Database.

I have managed to show the selected data, create a button to delete a specific Id but really needing some assistance with deleting the selected row or record instead of hard coding in the ID in my delete php script.

Here is an example of my script:

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, joinDate FROM customers";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                "<div class='trow'>" . 
                $row["id"]. ": " . 
                $row["firstname"] . " " . 
                $row["lastname"]. " " . 
                $row["joinDate"]. " " . 
                "<span class='deleteMember'>
                    <form action='deleteMember.php' method='POST'>
                        <button type='submit'>Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </span>" . " " . 
                "<span class='editMember'><a href='#'>Edit</a></span>" . 
                "<br></div>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Here is the delete.php

```
<?php

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id='6' ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

what I would like it to do is, delete the row from which you hit the delete button from and not just delete the row I have specified in the delete.php script. I understand HOW it should work by posting the id but not sure how to do it.

Comment: You might want to look into using GET for the delete button that sends request to your delete.php script. something like: delete.php?id=<if of row to delete>

Comment: Are you using PDO or `mysqli`?

Comment: @tadman By the looks of `num_rows` and `fetch_assoc()` I'd say mysqli.

Comment: MySQLi is one I am using because I trying to learn the basics - this is just learning how data is updated and deleted etc

Comment: @Maximus2012 They might not as well. You should *not* perform destructive actions with a `GET` request, and _especially_ not perform `DELETE`s with a `GET` request. If those URLs were crawled with a spider, every record would be deleted.

Comment: @MartinBean that is a valid point. However the OP needed to be aware of the basics first and the security element next (which is equally important)

Comment: Hey guys, I am aware there would be some massive security flaws with what I am doing, but I literally did just want to see how it works - I can then look into tightening up the security, believe me I am not looking into using this in the real world just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

?>

<?php

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, joinDate FROM customers";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                "<div class='trow'>" . 
                $row["id"]. ": " . 
                $row["firstname"] . " " . 
                $row["lastname"]. " " . 
                $row["joinDate"]. " " . 
                "<span><a href='deleteMember.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></span>" . 
                "<span class='editMember'><a href='#'>Edit</a></span>" . 
                "<br></div>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: this then takes me to a 404? I have taken the above but seems to be failing?

Comment: ok, sorry  i am editing change delete.php to deleteMember.php.

Comment: I need to point out that the method shown here is extremely unsafe and not to be used on any production envrionment, adding a `$_GET` value into a SQL query is a no no - let alone without cleaning it first!

Answer (score 1):

No need to add extra `form` element for Delete or Edit purpose. Try this way to pass the `id` of row for Eelete or Edit operation

```
while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
            $id=$row['id'];// capture your row id & pass to your delete & edit
            echo 
             "<div class='trow'>" . 
                 $row["id"]. ": " . 
                 $row["firstname"] . " " . 
                 $row["lastname"]. " " . 
                 $row["joinDate"]. " " . 
                 "<span class='deleteMember'>
                    <a href='deleteMember.php?id=<?=$id;?>'>Delete</a>
                 </span>" . " " . 
                 "<span class='editMember'>
                     <a href='editMember.php?id=<?=$id;?>'>Edit</a>
                 </span>" . 
                 "<br>
           </div>";
        }
```

**EDIT:**
Then catch the `id` on your relevant page for your operation.

//deleteMember.php

```
<?php
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id='".$id."'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

**Note:** Please Use Prepared Statements of `PDO` or `MYSQLi` instead to avoid `SQL Injection` and manual escaping.

Comment: And what should my SQL query look like in delete,php?

Comment: Can you spend the twenty seconds it takes to properly escape this thing before releasing it into the wild? Mumbling something about prepared statements is a nice gesture, but posting "working" code is not setting a very good example.

Comment: I am now getting an error 'Error deleting record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=' at line 1'

Answer (score 0):

in place of your form use this

```
<a href="deleteMember.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">DELETE</a>
```

and in your delete query must be like below

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' ";
```

Comment: No, no, no. Do not, ever, put `$_GET` directly in a query. This creates a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Also, as has been mentioned in another answer, don't use the `GET` method to perform an action on the server which has side effects. i.e. `GET` should not be used to do CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

or stay in your post form with:

```
 while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                "<div class='trow'>" . 
                $row["id"]. ": " . 
                $row["firstname"] . " " . 
                $row["lastname"]. " " . 
                $row["joinDate"]. " " . 
                "<span class='deleteMember'>
                    <form action='deleteMember.php' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='myid' value='".$row['id']."' />
                        <button type='submit'>Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </span>" . " " . 
                "<span class='editMember'><a href='#'>Edit</a></span>" . 
                "<br></div>";
        }
```

And in your delete.php :

```
<?php
    $id=(int) $_POST['myid'];

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id=".$id;

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Waving the `(int)` magic wand over data and then injecting that in a query is not really the right way to do it.

Comment: @tadman of course, it is just a more secure step to use with a prepare statment from pdo or mysqli. You can forget it or use it in addition with:
$q=$this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM customers WHERE id=:id');
$q->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute()

Comment: Using `prepare` makes it obvious and you have to go out of your way to get it wrong. Using `(int)` leaves room for serious mistakes, all it takes is forgetting once and you can be completely ruined.

Comment: @Tadman, please share your knowledge, i'm curious to see how it could ruin my code.  It is just to secure the received data, as if not int equal 0. It is also what is done when using PDO::PARAM_INT in bindvalue(). So using it together should be more secure than nothing at all.

Comment: The risk here is one day you forget to put in `(int)`, push the code to production without noticing, and someone with malicious intent finds out about it using a scanning tool. Then it's too late to fix. When using placeholders you have to make several mistakes before something awful happens, not just one.